# Delete local file(s) with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to delete local files by using jQuery?

I have tried deleting a local file called `log.html` that is in the same directory as my `index.php` file by using php.

This works, but I cannot use this as a function in jQuery, therefore I am looking for a jQuery alternative to this.

Comment: you can't because jQuery is Javascript, and javascript is client-side. You did with php because it is server-side. Just with some calls (lke ajax) to the server-side you will be able.

Comment: The term "Local" in this context is often used for "The clients machine". Your whole question gets odd by using the term, you can remove it and still have a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  delete a file using jQuery by sending an AJAX request to your PHP file and deleting the file from your php file.

Answer (score 1):

With pure jquery, it is not possible. AJAX request will do the job.